# Python hex to string?

Tags: python, string, hex, subprocess

I've generated a hex string using

```
x = os.system('openssl rand -hex 10')
```

But I'd like to use it as a string.

I've tried with `str(b0f4735701d6325fd072)` but it does not work.

also

```
>>> print(x)
7a7f13f40aac84332d44

>>> print("x is of type {}\nx has value {}".format(type(x), x))
x is of type <type 'int'>
x has value 0
```

Comment: `b0f4735701d6325fd072` is not a valid identifier in Python. Do you have `0xb0f4735701d6325fd072`?

Comment: Actually i was doing like x = os.system(openssl rand -hex 10) and saving it to a file with a string concatenation but it returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend, if you want to get this from a separate process, follow Python best practices and use the `subprocess` module. `check_output` will give you the `stdout` of the process that is kicked off. `shlex` can properly parse the shell command for you, don't do it manually:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('openssl rand -hex 10')
['openssl', 'rand', '-hex', '10']
>>> x = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('openssl rand -hex 10'))
>>> x
'42bfeea1f5a1d9b96e4b\n'
>>> x = x.strip()
>>> x
'42bfeea1f5a1d9b96e4b'
>>> int(x, 16)
315216711282402877075019L
```

To start with a proper hex literal, which begins with `0x`, 
which Python translates to a long int:

```
>>> 0xb0f4735701d6325fd072
835645817652699503513714L
```

Pass it to `hex`:

```
>>> hex(0xb0f4735701d6325fd072)
'0xb0f4735701d6325fd072L'
```

(You can strip the `L` from the string with `hex(0xb0f4735701d6325fd072).strip('L')`)

To convert back to a long from the string representation, you need to pass it to `int` (also `long` in Python 2) along with the proper base (16 in this case):

```
>>> int('0xb0f4735701d6325fd072', 16)
835645817652699503513714L
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an XY question because you don't know what `os.system` does.

`os.system` runs a shell command and returns the exit code. You mentioned that it's returning `0`, that's because it ran successfully.

Instead you should use `subprocess.check_output`.

```
import subprocess

hexcode = subprocess.check_output(["openssl", "rand", "-hex", "10"])
```

This will return as a string the output of the shell call `openssl rand -hex 10` rather than its exit code.

Comment: Wonderfull!! thanks buddy i've watched somewhere how to execute a shell command and it does but i didn't know that it returns the exit code >.<

Comment: You did this at the same time as myself, so +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could get random bytes using [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom):

```
>>> import binascii, os
>>> random_bytes = os.urandom(10)
>>> random_bytes
b'\xe4\x19\x9e\xbb\r\xe6C\xaa\x1e\x1f'
>>> binascii.hexlify(random_bytes)
b'e4199ebb0de643aa1e1f'
```

If you want to get an exception if the PRNG has not been seeded with enough data; you could use [`ssl.RAND_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.RAND_bytes):

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.RAND_bytes(10)
b'\xbdH\xec\xc2+\x03\x1f\x07\xd0R'
```

To get random bytes from `openssl` subprocess:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import subprocess
>>> hex_data = subprocess.check_output('openssl rand -hex 10'.split()).strip()
>>> hex_data
b'd310f3378f3e93e1f5ca'
>>> random_bytes = binascii.unhexlify(hex_data)
>>> random_bytes
b'\xd3\x10\xf37\x8f>\x93\xe1\xf5\xca'
```